# Run Lubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad t42

Tags: lubuntu

i've installed a Lubuntu 14.04 on my Old Thinkpad T42 notebook.... I use forcepae option to start installation!... at the end of the process after the log in the system propose to upgrade to 16.04 version with the command "release upgrade".....
There is Any way to run 14.04 without upgrading?
Thanks for the answers

Comment: why do you install a very old version?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc 14.04 is **LTS** - it has full support in terms of updates and security patches until **2019**. Ubuntu LTS releases are specifically designed for stability and robustness.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but so is 16.04 LTS. It is stable and robust until 2021

Answer (score 2):

*"There is Any way to run 14.04 without upgrading?"*

**Yes.** You will **never** be forced to upgrade. You can still run Ubuntu 10.04 if you want... (But don't do that)

Answer (score 2):

I have an IBM Thinkpad T42 too, and I have tested the current versions in it, including 16.04.1 LTS (supported until April 2019 and 16.10 (supported only for 9 months). I tested on behalf of the Lubuntu development team.

Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and 14.04.5 LTS are supported until April 2017. So in April you should either do a fresh installation or do a release upgrade, because there will be no more security updates of the Lubuntu specific program packages. (The packages 'under the hood' that belong to standard Ubuntu receive support until April 2019.)

-o-

It is easier and less risky to do a ***fresh installation***. You can keep the home directory (best but not necessary to have it in a separate partition). This means that you have to reinstall the extra packages that you installed, but the personal files, program settings and tweaks will survive.

If you want to ***do a release upgrade***, I suggest that you ***backup*** your system ***before*** starting, because of the risk, that the upgrade will fail.

Answer (score 1):

No one is forcing you to upgrade from any version to another , you run whatever version you like

PS : you can always disable release notification of 16.04 in Update Manager if you want.